# Fabric equivalent in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, deployment

Is there a Haskell tool equivalent to Python's [Fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org)?
Something to automate deployment to the production server?

Here are some of the things I want it to do (that I don't want to write in bash):

1. Ability to give it the "version" number to deploy
2. Upload a new compiled binary of the program to the server (possibly with rsync-like tool)
3. Checkout or export a given "tag" of the git or svn repo into a `webapps/site` directory
4. Restart a ubuntu's upstart job/service

Comment: Can you describe the features you want a bit more for those of us not familiar with fabric?

Comment: So... you want to run `uname` on many computers? Doesn't seem like you would need Haskell -- or even Python -- to do this. If that isn't all you want to do, well... update your description. I'm asking what _you_ want to do.

Comment: @DanielWagner I've updated my question with more concrete details (now hat I am closer to deployment of my project)

Comment: For me fabric is just remote execution, so the question title is too generic.

Answer (score 3):

Check out [Keter](https://github.com/snoyberg/keter), by Michael Snoyman who also created the Haskell web framework [Yesod](http://www.yesodweb.com/). It's a *deployment system for Yesod (and other Haskell) web apps*.

A more general purpose tool would be [Nemesis](https://github.com/nfjinjing/nemesis). *A rake like task management tool*, referencing Ruby's [Rake](http://rake.rubyforge.org/) tool.

Comment: Do you know of any Keter example configurations/scripts, as the readme is very scarce...